# What is the role of the proof system in a Henkin-proof of Completeness?

Tags: logic

Completeness is a property of proof systems. Roughly, we say that a proof system is complete iff truth implies derivability. Yet, the proofs for FOL we usually find in logic textbooks, i.e. "Henkin-proofs", do not seem to make any reference to any deductive system at all.

Consider the following proof sketch:

> > **Lemma 1 (Model Existence).** *$\Gamma$ is consistent $\Rightarrow \Gamma$ is satisfiable*
>
> Proof. Let $\mathcal{L}$ be our referring language. An usual proof goes more or less along the lines of
>
> 1. Let $\Gamma$ be consistent.
> 2. Extend $\Gamma$ to a maximal consistent set $\Delta$
> 3. Show that $\Delta$ preserves consistency and that $\Gamma \subseteq \Delta$
> 4. Define a valuation $v$ for $\Delta$ such that $v(\psi)=1$ iff $\psi \in \Delta$ for all atomic $\psi \in \mathcal{L}$
> 5. Define $v$'s unique extension $\bar v$ as usual.
> 6. Then $\bar v \vDash \Delta$ and, since $\Gamma \subseteq \Delta$,
> 7. $\bar v \vDash \Gamma$.
>    $\qquad \qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \Box$
>
> > **Theorem (Completeness)** $\Gamma \vDash \varphi \Rightarrow \Gamma \vdash \varphi$
>
> Proof. By contraposition. Let $\Gamma \nvdash \varphi$. Then $\Gamma \cup \{\neg \varphi\}$ is consistent and, by the Model Existence Lemma, it has a model. Hence, $\Gamma \nvDash \varphi$.
> $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \Box$

Note that I did not make any explicit mention to any intended deductive system at all. In fact, it seems to me the only syntactic notion I need is:

> **Definition (Consistency)** A set of sentences $\Gamma$ is consistent if there is $\varphi$ such that $\Gamma \nvdash \varphi$.

But yet, I can define this notion generally, for any deductive system.

Now I seemed to have proven completeness. But completeness *of which deductive system*? I don't know. For the above proof of completeness, I didn't make explicit any axiom or inference rule. This doesn't seem strange?

If this is so, it seems to me I could apply the same argument *mutatis mutandis* for any other deductive system (*even those for that are not complete?*).

> **Question**. What is the role of the proof system in a Henkin-proof of Completeness?

I am probably missing something. So can someone explain this topic in details?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Step 6 in your proof of model existence is not as obvious as it sounds!

For instance, imagine a deductive system which cannot conclude "$\varphi$" from "$\varphi\wedge \psi$". Then take $\Gamma=\{\varphi\wedge\psi, \neg\varphi\}$. $\Gamma$ is consistent for this proof system, but if we extend $\Gamma$ to a maximally consistent(-for-this-system) $\Delta$, the valuation $\nu$ you describe will **not** make $\Gamma$ true! So that's where the specifics of the proof system are hiding.

Comment: This is very similar to the point in my answer to your previous question, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449041/why-are-maximal-consistent-sets-essential-to-henkin-proofs-of-completeness/1449045#1449045.

Comment: Step 6 is indeed the place where you need that you're using the right deductive system and not something silly, but the deductive system also enters, in a weaker way, at step 2.  That step depends on the fact that, if a set of formulas is inconsistent, then so is some finite subset.  That is, you need that deductions are finite, because each rule has only finitely many premises.

Comment: @AndreasBlass that's a very good point - I was implicitly assuming that deductive systems are defined as monotonic maps from $\{$finite sets of formulas$\}$ to $\{$formulas$\}$.