# Logically, deductively, tautologically, semantically, syntactically valid arguments, what is the difference?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I've read 4 logic books in total but i'm getting crazy with all these xxxally valid argument what is the difference??  What is the difference between Logically, deductively, tautologically, semantically, syntactically valid arguments?

What is the difference between "the premises entail the conclusion", "inferring the conclusion from the premises" and "the premises logically imply the conclusion"?

All this makes me so confused. Could you guys clear things up for me a little please?
(i know i asked multiple question but they are all related, if it's a problem i can just delete it)

Answer (score 6):

This is a very annoying aspect of logic: there is a *lot* of terminological overload. This happens repeatedly *(e.g. in computability theory, also known as recursion theory, the terms "recursively enumerable," "computably enumerable," "semidecidable," and "recognizable" are all synonymous)*. Ironically, this largely stems from attempts to make the subject *more* understandable by using terms we have some intuition about.

Often the notation is much clearer than the terminology, even though it looks weirder. For example, in our case we have two relevant symbols, "$\vdash$" and "$\models$" *(LaTeX codes "\$\vdash\$" and "\$\models\$" respectively)*. The former corresponds to "syntactic deduction"/"syntactic entailment"/"provability," while the latter corresponds to "semantic deduction"/"semantic entailment"/"entailment."

For $\Gamma$ a set of sentences and $\varphi$ a single sentence, we have:

- $\Gamma\vdash\varphi$ means that there is some *formal proof* - in whatever system we're using - of $\varphi$ from $\Gamma$. A formal proof is a string of symbols following some basic rules; there's no discussion of what the sentences in our logic *mean*.

  - Note that a priori "$\vdash$" is ambiguous, since there are multiple proof systems out there (e.g. Hilbert style, sequent calculus, ...). Really we should distinguish the various $\vdash$s via subscripts (e.g. $\vdash_A$ vs. $\vdash_B$ for different proof systems $A$ and $B$), but in practice this isn't done in general since we can prove that all the usual ones are equivalent (see also the *completeness theorem* mentioned below).
- $\Gamma\models\varphi$ means that every structure satisfying $\Gamma$ also satisfies $\varphi$. That is, if $\mathcal{M}$ is a first-order structure and each sentence in $\Gamma$ is true in $\mathcal{M}$, then $\varphi$ is true in $\mathcal{M}$. For example, giving an example of a nonabelian group demonstrates that the group axioms do **not** entail, in the sense of $\models$, the sentence $\forall x,y(x*y=y*x)$.

  - The symbol "$\models$" is also used to relate *structures* to sentences: we write "$\mathcal{M}\models\varphi$" if $\varphi$ is true in $\mathcal{M}$. Similarly, there is an abuse of notation around sentences vs. sets of sentences: "$\mathcal{M}\models\Gamma$" means $\mathcal{M}\models\varphi$ for every $\varphi\in\Gamma$, "$\Gamma\models\Delta$" means that $\Gamma\models\varphi$ for every $\varphi\in\Delta$, "$\varphi\models\psi$" means $\{\varphi\}\models\psi$, etc.

Arguably the first real theorem in logic is that $\vdash$ and $\models$ coincide (at least when we use a reasonable proof system for $\vdash$): this is [**Godel's completeness theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem) *(yes, he proved a completeness theorem and an incompleteness theorem)*. This theorem is far from obvious; see my summary [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2099585/28111). This also explains why we can get away with using the term "entailment" rather sloppily: all the reasonable versions of syntactic entailment agree, and agree with semantic entailment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think i understand. Tautologically valid = Syntactically valid. Logically valid = deductively valid = semantically valid. Tautologically valid means that there is not valuation of that makes the premises true and the conclusion false. That is the inference holds in virtue of its form.
Deductively valid means that given that its premises are true, its conclusion is  guaranteed to be true as well, that is, if there is no possible situation in which the premises would be true and the conclusion false.

If the inference is tautologically valid then it's logically valid.

Comment: "Premises ⊨ conclusion" means that inference from the premises to the conclusion is tautologically valid and therefore also logically valid.


Premises⊢Conclusion when a chain of argument leads from the premises to the conclusion via intermediate valid inferential steps, then the argument constitutes a proof of the conclusion from those premisses. This is a syntactic relation because whether an array of wffs counts as a proof doesn't depend on their meaning, but only on whether the wffs are related in the ways allowed by the inference rules of the proof system.
Correct right?

Comment: Just a negligible remark. $\Gamma \models \Delta$ stands for $\Gamma \models \varphi$ for _some_ (and not every) $\varphi \in \Delta$. At least, this is meaning of $\Gamma \models \Delta$ to get the completeness theorem for the sequent calculus (and any other reasonable derivation system).

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco I'm not sure I agree. That's not how $\Gamma\models\Delta$ is used in any situation I've seen in writing. Only on the proof theory side are we really interested in sequents as such, and there we don't tend to use $\models$ at all. (But my experience is limited so I could easily be wrong.)

Answer (score 3):

We have a general concept of [Logical consequence](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-consequence/) with many "variants".

An argument:

> with premises in $\Gamma$ and conclusion $A$ is called "syntactically" (or deductively) valid when - with respect to a certain *proof system* $\mathsf {PS}$ - we have a derivation of $A$ from $\Gamma$ in the system.

In symbols: $\Gamma \vdash_{\mathsf {PS}}A$.

And:

> an argument with premises in $\Gamma$ and conclusion $A$ is a "semantically" valid if and only if there is no model $\mathcal M$ in which all members of $\Gamma$  are true and $A$ is false.

In symbols: $\Gamma \vDash A$.

The two definitions "track" each other through [soundness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness#Strong_soundness) and [completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(logic)#Strong_completeness):

> > $\Gamma \vdash A \text {  iff  } \Gamma \vDash A$.

---

[Validity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_(logic)) is the more general concept, while usually [tautologically validity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautological_consequence) is restricted to propositional calculus.

---

---

A very useful resource is: John Corcoran, [Three logical theories (*Phil.Sci*, 1969)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/186168?seq=1)