# What are the merits of having a "good" proof system?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory, philosophy, proof-theory

Background: My understanding is that model-theoretic semantics (MTS) and proof-theoretic semantics (PTS) differ in the following ways. In MTS, you first define the notion of truth in models and then having this notion you develop a "good" (sound, complete, decidable) proof system. In PTS, you just define a proof system and take this system itself to be the the definition of "truth", without even talking about models. So both MTS and PTS have proof systems, but these proof systems have different roles.

I understand why proof systems are needed in PTS: because that's the only thing you have in PTS -- there are no models. But what is the motivation behind studying proof systems in MTS, given that in MTS there is already a notion of truth (with respect to a model) defined? Why do we need an extra apparatus of proof system specifically in MTS?

Comment: Voting to close, because Math.SE isn't really the place for logicians to make sales pitches to linguists. What you noticed, however, is not specific to linguistics in any way: model theorists are generally interested in so-called semantic methods because that's what model theory is about. People who focus on proof systems tend not to be called model theorists in the first place. It's a bit like asking why brain surgeons tend to operate on the skull, and rarely on the eyes. They're close, there are shared skills and techniques, and cross-pollination, but ultimately these fields are distinct.

Comment: @Z.A.K. Correct me if I'm wrong but my understanding is that proof systems are used in both model-theoretic and proof-theoretic semantics. The only distinction is that in model-theoretic semantics, the notion of truth in a model is taken to be primary, whereas in proof-theoretic semantics the notion of a proof is taken to be primary. But still, in the context of model-theoretic semantics proof systems are used, they just play a role different from their role in proof-theoretic semantics. And my main question (the first two sentences of the second paragraph) has no relation to linguistics.

Comment: That is, in MTS, you define the notion of truth in models and then having this notion you develop a good proof system. But in PTS, you just define a proof system and take this system itself to be the the definition of "truth", without even talking about models. So both MTS and PTS have proof systems, but they have different roles. I understand why proof systems are needed in PTS (because that's the only thing you have in PTS -- there are no models), but my question is about the motivation of proof systems in MTS, given that in MTS there is already a notion of truth defined (w.r.t. a model).

Comment: I disagree with the close votes - I think that this is a fine question for MSE. There are lots of well-received questions on this site about explaining/motivating mathematical concepts to (for example) physicists, and I don't think this is really any different. That said, it might get better reception if restricted to the initial part - "what is the value of a 'good proof system' for  a model-theorist" - which already has plenty of content.

Comment: Okay, I made the question more "mathematical".

Comment: Mathematics is made of proofs.

Answer (score 5):

As someone who initially thought of the completeness theorem (= Godel's observation that first-order logic has a 'good proof system') as just an annoying digression from the really important semantics-focused model theory I was interested in, I think it helps to consider how the existence of a good proof system drastically improves complexity bounds. (See also the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099531/how-to-verify-satisfialibility-in-a-model-confusions-with-g%C3%B6dels-completeness) about whether/why the completeness theorem should be "expected.")

Suppose I have a logic $\mathcal{L}$ where the entailment relation $\models_\mathcal{L}$ is defined in some set-theoretic way - that is, $\mathfrak{M}\models_\mathcal{L}\Gamma$ means "There is some set-theoretic configuration 'built on' $\mathfrak{M}$ such that [properties]." In the case $\mathcal{L}=\mathsf{FOL}$, this set-theoretic configuration is just a collection of Skolem functions (or similar) witnessing the truth of the relevant sentences. The point is that at first glance the induced entailment relation on (sets of) sentences is [$\Pi_1$ in the **Levy** hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_hierarchy): "$\Gamma\models_\mathcal{L}\varphi$" means "There is no structure-plus-configuration pair $(\mathfrak{M}, \mathbb{X})$ such that $\mathbb{X}$ witnesses the truth in $\mathfrak{M}$ of $\Gamma\cup\{\neg\varphi\}$." The existence of a good proof system brings things all the way down to [$\Sigma_1^{0}$ in the **arithmetical** hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy), since we can replace "There is no countermodel" with "There is a proof." This is a gulf in complexity that is difficult to appropriately summarize; suffice to say that it's quite impressive! Even if you don't care about decidability issues, the indicates a genuine reduction in the ontological commitments needed to make sense of the surrounding questions. (It also forms a nice contrast with the situation with respect to *Herbrand semantics*; in Herbrand semantics, the individual elements considered are much simpler but the entailment relation induced is much more complicated. See [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/67547/is-herbrand-semantics-a-kind-of-term-formalism/69960#69960).)

Admittedly, it is absolutely possible to do lots of research in model theory using just the **compactness theorem**. Think of the compactness theorem as saying that a good proof system exists for $\mathsf{FOL}$ *except maybe* it might be really computationally complicated. It turns out that for most pure model-theoretic questions, we really only care about the "finite based"-ness of $\models_{\mathsf{FOL}}$, that is, the fact that $\Gamma\models_\mathsf{FOL}\varphi$ iff $\Gamma_0\models_{\mathsf{FOL}}\varphi$ for some finite $\Gamma_0\subseteq \Gamma$. I have two responses to this:

- There are times that you do care about the exact complexity of $\models_\mathsf{FOL}$, and for this an explicit proof system is really the best way to package all the necessary information. (For example, look at the *arithmetized completeness theorem* in the context of model theory of theories of arithmetic, like first-order Peano arithmetic.)
- We should always be looking for ways to **connect** seemingly-disparate perspectives on any piece of mathematics, and the broad topic of "structures, theories, and properties" is no different. I would provocatively, but not wholly jokingly, say that the real value of the completeness theorem to the model theorist (*over* compactness as such) is that it helps develop connections with proof theory.

Comment: I am glad to read your answer. I also use your complexity argument to explain the relevance of the completeness theorem. But I always add that I do not know of any application (outside logic/metamatematics) of this surprising result.