# A consistent set of formulas is satisfiable.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> Is the following proof correct, or I miss something?

**Lemma**
A consistent set of formulas is satisfiable.

**Proof**

Let be $\Sigma$ is consistent set of formulas, thus, from Proposition ???, there is no $\alpha$ such that $\Sigma\vdash\alpha$ and $\Sigma\vdash\neg\alpha$. Thus we can define a truth assignment 
$u$ as follows:
\begin{equation}
u(\alpha)=\begin{cases}\top&\text{if $\Sigma\vdash\alpha$}\\
\bot&\text{if $\Sigma\vdash\neg\alpha$}\\
\top\text{ (or $\bot$)}&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

For all $\beta\in\Sigma$ we have $\Sigma\vdash\beta$, thus $u(\beta)=\top$. 
Therefore $\Sigma$ is satisfiable.

**Definitions**

I use a definition of *consistent* that I proved (Proposition ???) to be equivalent to 'there is no $\alpha$ such that $\Sigma\vdash\alpha$ and $\Sigma\vdash\neg\alpha$'.

A set of formula $\Sigma$ is *satisfiable* if there is a truth assignment that satisfies all formula in $\Sigma$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect: consider the situation where we have two propositional atoms $p$ and $q$, and $\Sigma=\emptyset$ (so doesn't prove anything other than tautologies). According to your definition of $u$, there is no restriction on what truth values can be assigned to each of the following sentences (each of which is undecidable in $\Sigma$):

- $p$,
- $q$,
- $\neg(p\wedge q)$.

However, clearly we can't assign each of them "$\top$." So your approach for defining a valuation for $\Sigma$ needs to be more complicated: it needs to take into account how the various sentences, *even those undecidable in $\Sigma$*, interact with each other.

---

Note that this problem would not arise if we assumed additionally that $\Sigma$ was **complete**: that is, for each $\varphi$, either $\varphi\in \Sigma$ or $\neg\varphi\in\Sigma$. (Indeed, then the third clause of your definition of $u$ would be unnecessary.) So what is immediately true is:

> $(*)\quad$ Any complete consistent theory has a model.

So now you need to prove:

> $(**)\quad$ Any consistent theory is contained in a complete consistent theory.

---

It's also worth mentioning for contrast what happens in [**first-order logic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic). (In particular, [this old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449041/why-are-maximal-consistent-sets-essential-to-henkin-proofs-of-completeness/1449045) nicely parallels yours.)

In first-order logic, the notion of satisfiability is more complex: a model is *not* just a truth assignment. We still have ["consistency implies satisfiability"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem) (for the right proof system, anyways), but the proof is a bit more complicated. However, it evolves quite nicely from the proof of the completeness theorem for propositional logic; [see this exposition by Bezhanishvili](https://www.cs.nmsu.edu/historical-projects/Projects/completeness.pdf).

Comment: Great! the notes that I follow have no single proof, but they have the lemma 'satisfiable implies consistent' at the beginning and 'consistent implies satisfiable' after the lemmas about maximally consistent. I made the error to move the 2nd together with the 1st. now I understand why. I assume that your complete is in "my" 'maximally consistent', and my truth assignment is your model or valuation.

Comment: Your (**) is probably my 'Given a consistent set of formulas $\Sigma$, there is a maximally consistent set of formulas 
$\Gamma$ such that $\Sigma\subset\Gamma$.'